# I want to check for a input values of a textfield is float or int or string in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to check whether the input value of a textfield is float or int and the rest is strings.

For example, if the user has entered 43.34 in textfield, we will get it as a string . After obtain the string value i have to identify whether it is float or int.

```
if (value is float)
{
    // do something
} 
else if (value is int)
{
    // do some thing
}
else
{
    // this is a string value
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What exactly is your problem or question?

Comment: @milesper : I want to check the input value from text field as float or int and call respective save methods

Answer (score 2):

Because a number is float also is integer .
So you must check if a number is integer first , then float and last string.

```
- (BOOL)checkIsInteger: (NSString *)integerString{
    NSScanner* scan = [NSScanner scannerWithString:integerString];
    int val;
    return [scan scanInt:&val] && [scan isAtEnd];
}

- (BOOL)checkIsFloat: (NSString *)floatString{
    NSScanner* scan = [NSScanner scannerWithString:floatString];
    float val;
    return [scan scanFloat:&val] && [scan isAtEnd];
}

- (void)yourFunction: (NSString *)string{
    if ([self checkIsInteger:string]) {
        // This is integer
    }else if([self checkIsFloat:string]){
        // This is float
    }else
        // This is string
}
```